# HTTP Response Question

Tags: http, proxy, http-status-codes

Is it valid to return different text in the response header than the usual fare?

For example if the request is invalid, could I respond with:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Here be Dragons
```

And have that header properly handled by proxies, etc?

Comment: Are you writing the only application for this rest service?

Comment: This is no big deal, but I just want to point out that this isn't really about REST, it's about HTTP.

Comment: Fair point Avi. I'll change the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it conforms to the HTTP protocol to have arbitrary text on the response line. No, proxies aren't required to forward that as-is (but typically will).

Answer (score 2):

The [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1) says:

> The Status-Code is intended for use by automata and the Reason-Phrase is intended for the human user. The client is not required to examine or display the Reason-Phrase.

and:

> The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations -- they MAY be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol.

So yes, it's valid to use any text you'd like as the Reason-Phrase AKA "Status text" or "Status name".